# Listview builder only different values

Tags: flutter, listview, stream-builder

I have a listview builder inside a Stream Builder, the content is gotten in a Snapshot, however, the problem I'm having is that I need to display the repeated data only once.

[image: Noitifications]

As you see, the same person viewed a listing and send me some chats, how can I tell the Listview Builder Return, to only create the widget if the person and action is different in this example instead of 6 Eduardo Alas view your listing and 4 Eduardo Alas Wants to send you a message, I want to display only 2 rows as it is a repeated action.

Here is my Code:

```
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: DatabaseMethods().getNotifications(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      int lastdoc = 0;
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        lastdoc = snapshot.data.docs.length - 1;
                      }
                      return snapshot.hasData
                          ? Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                color: Color(0xFFF9F7F0),
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                                    reverse: false,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                                      DocumentSnapshot ds =
                                          snapshot.data.docs[index];

                                      return NotificationInfo(
                                        id: ds.id,
                                        email: ds['email'],
                                        image: ds['image'],
                                        name: ds['name'],
                                        phone: ds['phone'],
                                        platform: ds['platform'],
                                        token: ds['token'],
                                        typeNot: ds['notification'],
                                        username: ds['username'],
                                        listingId: ds['listingId'],
                                        listingImage: ds['listingImage'],
                                        notificationId: ds.id,
                                        blockDemo: false,
                                        islast: index == lastdoc,
                                      );
                                      //}
                                    }),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Center(
                              child: RoofLoadingBar(
                                height: 100,
                              ),
                            );
                    },
                  )
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you could do is avoid saving multiple instances for when one viewed a listing or wants to send you a message,

In the case of sending a message , you can use `userid` as `doc id` , this means that you can only have one message request from a user.WHen writing to firebase , you will parse a `docId` and use `create_or_update`  `.set` to write your data, example :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("notifications")
          .doc(userid)
          .set({"mymap":"data as usual"});
```

In the case of listing you can concatenate `userid` and `listingId`, using `.set` save the data , you can have a counter field .

```
String? myDocId= userid+listingId;
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("notifications")
              .doc(myDocId)
              .set({"mymap":"data as usual"});
```